# Пагинация путем "Предыдущих записей"

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас на многих сайтах реализована такая штука, если на странице много материала, стандартную постраничную навигацию не применяют, а ставят кнопку "Предыдущие записи" и при нажатии на неё подгружаются более ранние записи.
Собственно вопрос, как сделать такую штуку? Подгрузка записей без перезагрузки страницы, это я так понимаю ajax, интересует другое, а именно, как должен выглядеть сам запрос на выборку более ранних записей mysql?
Может у кого ссылка есть где подробно об этом рассказывается?

Comment: Если у последней выведенной записи `id = 123`, то запрос строится с условием `id < 123`. Ну и лимит по количеству.

Comment: Ну, допустим, первые записи выводим к примеру так:  

    $limit = 15   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news LIMIT $limit")  

Как теперь вывести следующие 15 записей?

Comment: понял, спасибо

Comment: @KiTe, не думаю что привязка к id хорошая идея. Я бы например, взял бы дату публикаций записи.

Comment: в таком случае дата должна быть уникальным ключом

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, если поле id с автоинкрементом, то способ выборки предложенный @KiTE - это идея хорошая. Исключением может быть только, если дата вносится вручную. В таком случае, более ранняя запись может иметь дату "свежее", чем у последующей записи.

Comment: @Deonis, и я об этом тоже хтел сказать. Если создать запись с датой год назад вот тогда интересно получиться с автоинкрементами. И вообще, я сомневаюсь что даты тоже справятся с ТЗ. Хотя, кто знает, нужно подумать...

Comment: Я описал общую идею. Разумеется отталкиваться можно не только от ID.

Comment: Дата в принципе может изменяться, например если отредактировать сообщение, как например на хэше можно редактировать комментарии и ответы, при этом будет нарушена последовательность сообщений, если сортировать по дате, а ИД постоянен, также никто не застрахован от двух одинаковых дат в базе. ИД лучше наверно все-таки для выборки.

Comment: От двух одинаковых дат страховка в unixtime, по крайней мере можно предусмотреть уникальность дат без особого ущерба. Последовательность тем - вещь абстрактная, в частности на ХК темы апаются, в которых были изменения, - это фича, а не баг.Кроме того, если в неких статьях на неком сайте, например, редактируют дату, то делают это с какой-то целью. В жж любят делать пост-дисклеймер с датой на несколько лет вперед, тогда он будет виден на главной странице для новых посетителей.Порядок в выборке должен выбрать хозяин ресурса и соответствующее условие для следующих страниц должно вытекать из этого

Answer (score 1):

Уточню выборку первых записей. С учетом сортировки запрос должен быть таким:

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Следующие записи выбираются запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id < 12345 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Где 12345 - id последней записи выбранной первым запросом.

И так далее...